# Is there analog of fmt:formatNumber in velocity like in jsp?

Tags: jsp, formatting, velocity, template-engine

Now I am migrating my jsp to velocity template.
I cannot find solution how to migrate following code line:

```
<fmt:formatNumber minFractionDigits='2' value='${campaign.budget div 100}'/>
```

Does velocity can something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$numberTool.format("#0.00", $val)`
You should see 'org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.NumberTool' for more details.

To make it working you also should add the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and write following code:

```
context.put("numberTool", new NumberTool());
```

Comment: Yes, I saw following solution, but I have a problem. when I write          context.put("numberTool", new NumberTool());   IDE diesn't know about  NumberTool

Comment: Try rebuild your application. What is your IDE?

Comment: I edited your answer with helpful for me information

Comment: You are welcome, This is my bad when my answer lack of information :)